# Laravel mocked class in another test treated as though it exists

Tags: laravel, mockery

Using Laravel 5.8, I have the following 2 tests within the same test class:

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function a_procurement_group_can_be_created_or_fetched_from_odoo_for_this_shipment()
{
    $shipment = InboundShipment::make();

    $group = $this->mock(ProcurementGroup::class, function($group) {
        $group->shouldReceive('findByNameOrCreate')
            ->with('foo')
            ->andReturnSelf();
    });

    $this->assertSame($group, $shipment->getProcurementGroup('foo'));
}

/**
 * @test
 */
public function a_procurement_can_be_created_for_an_item_in_the_shipment()
{
    $shipment = InboundShipment::make();

    $group = app(ProcurementGroup::class);

    $procurement = app(ProcurementOrder::class);

    $item = $this->mock(InboundShipmentItem::class);

    $item->shouldReceive('createProcurement')
        ->once()
        ->with($group)
        ->andReturn($procurement);

    $result = $shipment->createProcurementForItem($item, $group);

    $this->assertSame($procurement, $result);
}
```

The `ProcurementGroup` class does not actually exist yet, however, in the first test I'm able to mock it and use it. Great.

Now, in the second test, I would expect to receive an error from the `$group = app(ProcurementGroup::class);` line since the class does not exist, but instead both test pass.

However, if I run only the second test by itself, then I do receive the error that the `ProcurementGroup` class does not exist.

So it seems that mocking the class in the first test is causing the second test to think the class actually exists. Is this expected behavior?

I was under the impression that since Laravel calls `Mockery::close()` in the `tearDown` method of its base test case, that all mock information should be destroyed in between each test.

What is going on here?

Comment: Have you changed the `setUp`/`tearDown` methods in this test class?

Comment: @Borisu No I have not.

Comment: Can you try to `dd($group);` in the second test and run them both?